# SwipeRefreshLayout is not working inside viewpager layout in android fragment

Tags: android

```
//when i tried to wrap to this code with viewpager ....everything works fine but the swiperefresh icon seems to not working properly
    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/sweeprefresh"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:id="@+id/activity_main"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:weightSum="1"
            tools:context="shuresnepali.jsoup.MainActivity">

            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/progressBar"
                style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="10dp" />

            <WebView
                android:id="@+id/web"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="334dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.72"></WebView>
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayo
```

// here is my java code....when i remove pageviewer it works pretty 
fine...i have been looking for this anwser on google...but nothing happend...
here is my java code....when i remove pageviewer it works pretty 
fine...i have been looking for this anwser on google...but nothing happend...
    package shuresnepali.jsoup;

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

import java.io.IOException;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    WebView webView;
    ProgressBar progressBar;
    SwipeRefreshLayout swipe;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        swipe = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.sweeprefresh);
        swipe.setDistanceToTriggerSync(50);
        swipe.setColorSchemeResources(android.R.color.holo_blue_dark, android.R.color.holo_green_light, android.R.color.holo_red_dark, android.R.color.holo_purple);
        swipe.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
                                       @Override
                                       public void onRefresh() {
                                           swipe.setRefreshing(true);
                                           new Thread(new Runnable() {
                                               @Override
                                               public void run() {
                                                   Elements pages = null;
                                                   Document doc;
                                                   try {
                                                       for (int i = 2; i <= 13; i++) {
                                                           Document doc1 = Jsoup.connect("http://www.onlinekhabar.com/content/news/page/" + i + "/").get();
                                                           Elements container = doc1.select("#archlist");
                                                           Elements remove = container.select("#arch_title,.clear,.share_loop,.share_loop_dvd").remove();
                                                           Elements item = container.select(".news_loop").attr("style", "background-color:lightgray;padding:5px;margin-top:3px;border-radius:2px;");
                                                           Elements a = item.select("a").attr("style", "color:brown;text-decoration:none");
                                                           Elements img = item.select("img").remove();

                                                           if (i == 2) {
                                                               pages = container;
                                                           } else {
                                                               pages.select(".news_loop").last().after(container.html());
                                                           }
                                                       }
                                                       webView.loadData(pages.html(), "text/html; charset=UTF-8", null);

                                                   } catch (IOException e) {
                                                       e.printStackTrace();
                                                   }
                                               }
                                           }).start();
                                       }
                                   }
        );

        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int newProgress) {

                if (newProgress < 100 && progressBar.getVisibility() == ProgressBar.GONE) {
                    progressBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.VISIBLE);
                }
                progressBar.setProgress(newProgress);
                if (newProgress == 100) {
                    progressBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.GONE);
                }
                progressBar.setProgress(newProgress);
            }
        });
        webView.setWebViewClient(new Mywebview());
    }


    class Mywebview extends WebViewClient {
        String h;

        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(final WebView view, String url) {
            swipe.setEnabled(false);
            h = url;
            linkOpenView viewok = new linkOpenView();
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Document doc;
                    Elements elements;
                    try {
                        doc = Jsoup.connect(h).get();
                        elements = doc.select(".ok-single-content");
                        Elements p = elements.select("p").attr("style", "color:brown");
                        Elements img_size = p.select("img").attr("style", "width:150px;height:120px");
                        view.loadData(elements.html(), "text/html; charset=UTF-8", null);
                        view.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
                            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int newProgress) {
                                progressBar.setProgress(newProgress);
                                if (newProgress < 100 && progressBar.getVisibility() == ProgressBar.GONE) {
                                    progressBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.VISIBLE);
                                }
                                progressBar.setProgress(newProgress);
                                if (newProgress == 100) {
                                    progressBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.GONE);
                                }

                            }
                        });
                        view.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
                            @Override
                            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                                if ((keyCode == event.KEYCODE_BACK) && view.canGoBack()) {
                                    view.goBack();
                                }
                                return true;
                            }

                        });
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }).start();
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            swipe.setRefreshing(false);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello! I'm no android export, but perhaps it might be usefull to add your `java` source as well.